# how to access returned array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have following condition in my code. I am returning an array of objects from a function.

```
function convertPxToMeters(pixPosX, pixPosY)
{
//some further code
    var meterPosArray = new Object();


    // i have xPosMeters and yPos Meters filled correctly
    meterPosArray['xpos'] = xPosMeters;
    meterPosArray['ypos'] = yPosMeters;

    return meterPosArray;

}
```

however, when i access the return value it says undefined when i try to print value of returned array in alert box. I am doing something wrong while accessing returned array because I printed the meterPoxArray values and they have right values in it.

Can someone please help me how can I access the return values from the returned array ?

```
var pixRatArr = new Object();
pixRatArr = convertPxToMeters(x,y);

//following says undefined value in alert box
alert("hidden element 1: "+pixRatArr['xPos']);
```

Thanks

Comment: `xpos` and `xPos` are different.

Comment: aside: there's no reason to create, then throw away an `Object`. Just say: `var pixRatArr = convertPxToMeters(x,y);`

Comment: my bad, Looks like i need some sleep now :( ... thanks a lot to point that out ! Yeah, I was just trying to new it but now I see why it was not working !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript object keys are case sensitive.

'xpos' is not the same as 'xPos'.

Comment: I guess this is a typo and the question should be closed as such.

Comment: Maybe; unless the user didn't know that hash keys are case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks Paul and Felix. Yeah I knew that it is case sensitive but I just missed it somehow. This question can be closed now.

Answer (score 3):

```
alert("hidden element 1: "+pixRatArr['xPos']);
```

Should be:

```
alert("hidden element 1: "+pixRatArr['xpos']);
```

Case-sensitivity matters...

Comment: Typo questions should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

```
function convertPxToMeters(pixPosX, pixPosY)
{
    //some further code
    var meterPosArray = new Object();
    // i have xPosMeters and yPos Meters filled correctly
    meterPosArray["xpos"] = pixPosX;
    meterPosArray["ypos"] = pixPosY;

    return meterPosArray;
}
```

Change the way you declare pixRatArr

```
<script>
    var pixRatArr = convertPxToMeters("12","13");
    //following says undefined value in alert box
    alert("hidden element 1: "+pixRatArr["xpos"]);
</script>
```